# product types with and without variants

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I have two product types. One has variants. One has not.

So I try to write an image tag that works for both.

```
{% set imageThumb = item.defaultVariant.variantThumb.one()  %}
```

For the product with one variant this returns:

> Impossible to invoke a method ("one") on a null variable.

This works only for the product type with multiple variants. `defaultVariant` doesn't seem to be present on products with just one variant.

Trying to fit both cases with one and with multiple variants:

```
{% for item in craft.products.all() %}
   {% if item.defaultVariant | length %}
     {% set imageThumb = item.defaultVariant.variantThumb.one()  %}
   {% else %}
      {% set imageThumb = item.variantThumb.one()  %}
   {% endif %}
      <img src="{{ imageThumb.url }}"
 {% endfor %}
```

This code is not working. How do I have to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `item.defaultVariant` will always be true even for products without visible variants (see [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v3/products.html#default-variant) on that), so you can't test for it.

You don't really need to test for it though - just look first for images held against the product, and fallback to images held against the default variant like this:

```
{% for item in craft.products.all() %}
    {% set imageThumb = item.variantThumb|length ? item.variantThumb.one() :
        item.defaultVariant.variantThumb|length ? item.defaultVariant.variantThumb.one() 
    %}
    <img src="{{ imageThumb.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```